# EC2 Windows User Data: Script does not run as expected

Tags: batch-file, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, user-data

I need run my custom script when new instance initiated. Minimum instance configuration is 2 so that i always have 2 instance running.

I did the following steps to configure and check the user data;

1. Create an AMI of one of the instance say instance1.
2. Copy Launch configuration from the existing one and change the AMI to the new one i created.
3. In the advanced details, user data i pasted the following scripts as a sample

```html
<script>
    echo Current date and time >> %SystemRoot%\Temp\test.log
    echo %DATE% %TIME% >> %SystemRoot%\Temp\test.log
</script>
```

3. I update the launch configuration of auto scaling group to the new one
4. I terminate another instance which i didn't took AMI so that new instance automatically initiated and my user data need to be executed

After initiated, i go to the remote desktop and check the *%SystemRoot%\Temp* path, but test.log not created.

So i verified the log as specified in the aws document and find the following log

```
2018/06/07 00:21:01Z: Userdata execution begins
2018/06/07 00:21:01Z: Zero or more than one <persist> tag was not provided
2018/06/07 00:21:01Z: Unregistering the persist scheduled task
2018/06/07 00:21:03Z: Zero or more than one <runAsLocalSystem> tag was not provided
2018/06/07 00:21:03Z: Zero or more than one <script> tag was not provided
2018/06/07 00:21:03Z: Zero or more than one <powershellArguments> tag was not provided
2018/06/07 00:21:03Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2018/06/08 09:41:39Z: Userdata execution begins
2018/06/08 09:41:39Z: Failed to get metadata: The result from http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data was empty
2018/06/08 09:41:44Z: Unable to execute userdata: Userdata was not provided
2018/06/08 09:41:44Z: Userdata execution done
2018/06/08 10:26:28Z: Userdata execution begins
2018/06/08 10:26:28Z: Failed to get metadata: The result from http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data was empty
2018/06/08 10:26:32Z: Unable to execute userdata: Userdata was not provided
2018/06/08 10:26:32Z: Userdata execution done
```

Can anyone help me where i missed?

Comment: Given your batch-file tag, I have no idea what relationship your log file data has with a batch file or why you've provided `cmd.exe` syntax code within `<script />` tags. What is your specific question? and do you have permissions for writing to `%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp`?

Comment: We have configured for auto scaling. Here i need to run my scripts when new instance up. For that i created one custom image of existing instance and configure new Launch configuration with the provided script. But when a new instance came the script didnt run as expected

Comment: A batch file is a text file with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension which contains lines of commands to be run by the command interpreter, _commonly, `cmd.exe` on Windows Operating Systems_. Is that what you've got?

Comment: i have .cmd file but it didnt executed. But now i done by creating a windows tasks scheduler to run that script at startup and took image and configure in the load balanacer